# How to query a specific view in sharepoint via powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

So i've been trying to query a specific view for a list i have in sharepoint. The view is called "Pending" but im not sure where to apply the view within the code.

```
Function Get-ListItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context, [String]$ListTitle) {
$list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
$qry = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery() 
$items = $list.GetItems($qry)
$Context.Load($items)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
return $items}
```

It currently just takes in every entry within the list, regardless of what view they are in but i want it to only query the entries that are "Pending".

Answer (score 1):

You will want to extend the function with an extra parameter for the name of the view.

I cannot test this myself, but this might work for you:

```
function Get-ListItemsFromView {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)]
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context, 

        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$ViewName,

        [Parameter(Position = 2, Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$ListTitle
    )


    $list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
    $Context.Load($list)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    $view = $list.Views.GetByTitle($ViewName)
    $Context.Load($view)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    $qry = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $qry.ViewXml = $view.ViewQuery

    $items = $list.GetItems($qry)
    $Context.Load($items)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    return $items
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Views are not a data type in SharePoint. SharePoint knows only `List` and `Library` objects. Views are just ASP.NET Web Forms pages created by SharePoint. Filtering the `Approval Status` column in the list must be what you are looking for.

```
function Get-PendingListItems
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection])]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$false,
                   Position=0)]
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]
        $Context,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$false,
                   Position=1)]
        [String]
        $ListTitle
    )
    Process
    {
        # Fail Fast
        try {
            $list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
        } catch {
            Write-Error "The list $ListTitle does not exist."
            return $null
        }

        $query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery;

        # You can select the fields you would like to view. For more information look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms470490(v=office.14)
        # $query.ViewFields = '<ViewFields><FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef><FieldRef Name="Title"></FieldRef></ViewFields>';

        # 2 means pending. For More information look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spmoderationstatustype?view=sharepoint-server
        $query.Query = '<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus" /><Value Type="ModStat">2</Value></Eq></Where>';

        $items = $list.GetItems($query)
        $Context.Load($items)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()

        return $items
    }
    End
    {
        $Context.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Here we have created a CAML query that filters only items with `Approval Status` as `Pending`. The number `2` means `Pending`, as you can see in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spmoderationstatustype?view=sharepoint-server). You can filter the properties to return but I have commented out the line since it is not mandatory. You can have a look at that on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms470490(v=office.14)).